# Case Assignment Rule

Tags: lightning, case, assignment-rules, lightning-quickaction

One Javascript button on Lead page used to create cases, when the case gets created then Assignment Rule assign that case to the queue, and the user doesn't have access to view that case hence user will see the message below:
[image]
**The case has been successfully saved and assigned to the appropriate user or queue according to the active assignment rule. You no longer have access to view or edit this case.**

When I converted that Javascript Button in Salesforce Quick Action for Lightning then case gets created and assigned to queue in backend, as user doesn't have access for that case hence the 'Unable to load' message appears on the tab and an endless spinner is displayed.
[image]

Is there any limitation in **Salesforce Lightning**, so as not to see this message.